# Hazelcast Jet - Pattern matching

Tags: hazelcast-jet

Does hazelcast jet support pattern matching use cases like few of the even stream processors support.

If not, will this be included in the future release.

Here is an use ase for pattern matching

Find the trader who sold 'AAA'  stock followed by bought 
'BBB'  stock in 10 seconds time frame.

Comment: Explain "pattern matching". Jet can match many kinds of patterns.

Comment: Here I mean followed by event. For e.g.  Find the trader who sold 'AAA' stock followed by bought 'BBB' stock in 10 seconds time frame.

Comment: You can do this using a 10 second sliding window + an aggregate operation using trader Id as key.